# Pandas reading excel file with simple multicolumn index

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have an excel file which looks like this

[image]

When I read this whith pandas.read_excel pandas returns a df which looks like this:

```
                                        1998 Unnamed: 1  1999 Unnamed: 3  \
Angélus                                   20        -35    16         au   
Angludet                                  17         au    16         vo   
Arnaud de Jacquemeau                      16         vo    16         vo   
Ausone                                    20        -40    18        -25   
Barde-Haut                                17         au    17         vo
```

Is there a way to tell pandas about the multicolumn so that the output is either

```
                                        1998       1998  1999       1999
Angélus                                   20        -35    16         au   
Angludet                                  17         au    16         vo   
Arnaud de Jacquemeau                      16         vo    16         vo   
Ausone                                    20        -40    18        -25   
Barde-Haut                                17         au    17         vo
```

or

```
                                               1998            1999
Angélus                                   20        -35    16         au   
Angludet                                  17         au    16         vo   
Arnaud de Jacquemeau                      16         vo    16         vo   
Ausone                                    20        -40    18        -25   
Barde-Haut                                17         au    17         vo
```

?

Thx Patrik

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
df.columns = df.columns.to_series().str.replace(r'^Unnamed', np.nan).fillna(method='ffill').tolist()
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to create a new column list & then redefine the column names like below :

```
df.columns = df.columns.astype(str)    
new_columns = [df.columns[i-1]  if df.columns[i].find("Unnamed") >= 0 else df.columns[i] for i in range(len(df.columns))]
df.columns = new_columns
```

or you could do it in a single line by

```
df.columns = [df.columns[i-1]  if df.columns[i].find("Unnamed") >= 0 else df.columns[i] for i in range(len(df.columns))]
```

Comment: Thats a nice one. Thanks

Comment: @Pat if this resolves you problem, please mark this as the answer.